# list enabled service instances

Tags: 17.04, services, systemd, multiple-instances

I'd like to list all enabled service instances.

The following lists enabled services, but only shows the service, and not individual instance:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
```

The following lists all running instances:

```
systemctl list-units --state=running
```

I would expect something like the following to show enabled instances:

```
systemctl list-units --state=enabled
```

But that does not work.

So, if I start two service instances with:

```
systemctl start foo-service@primary
systemctl start foo-service@secondary
```

...but then I only enable one:

```
systemctl enable foo-service@secondary
```

The only way I've been able to find out which instances are enabled is with:

```
ls /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/
```

But that seems very kludge-y.  Is there a systemd way of doing this?  Version is 232 if it matters.

Comment: You should mention the version of `system` you are using.

Comment: This question is more or less identical to [a question](https://serverfault.com/q/940982/90881) on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

One solution I found was to list all of the units (which will include all instances of a templated service), and use `xargs` to run a command for each unit (checking whether each one is enabled):

```
$ systemctl list-units --no-legend | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "%: $(systemctl is-enabled %)"'
auditd.service: enabled
chronyd.service: enabled
crond.service: enabled
...
```

To explain what is going on here:

- `systemctl list-units --no-legend` : List all systemd units, without showing the headers at the top of the ouput
- `awk '{print $1}'` : Print the first part of each line, which is the name of the unit
- `xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "%: $(systemctl is-enabled %)"'` : Runs a command for line of the piped input. This will echo the unit name, followed by the output of `systemctl is-enabled <service>`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to adapt it to only output enabled instances like so: `systemctl list-units --plain --no-legend my@\*.service | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r -I % sh -c 'systemctl is-enabled % > /dev/null && echo %' sh`. I added the filter `my@\*.service` because I only cared about instances of one particular service.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'grep' to search for and list the enabled services

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, `list-unit-files` only shows enabled services, not enabled instances.